# Can't edit combo box value in CFiledialog in Windows XP SP3

Tags: mfc, windows-xp, arabic, right-to-left, cfiledialog

The Custome `FileDialog` which I derived from `CFiledialog`.
In it's `OnInitDialog()` I updated it's layout to `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL` (for arabic) then I set callback method `SetChildLayout` to Enumerate all child item and set it's layout to `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL`.

After doing all these things when dialog is up, I can't access filename combo box. It's type is `CComboBoxEx`.

I can edit combo box only after resizing my custome dialog.

Any idea?

Comment: When you say *"I can't access filename combo box"* this isn't very helpful. You need to provide the relevant code to minimize the guesswork.